# setting a minimum height and layout weight on edit text android

Tags: android, layout

I have a form with an EditText that I want to fill any remaining space. It works but when you click to edit the text (in the emulator) it decreases the height of the EditText which I actually kind of want but only to a certain point. When you hit a key on the keyboard it brings up the word suggestion box and decreases the height even further to where it's no longer readable. I tried using the android:minHeight attribute but it doesn't seem to do anything when I also use android:layout_weight.
Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@raw/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFuture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set for future time?"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbFuture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBody"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Body" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnOK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:text="OK" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The EditText in question is etBody. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I plugged your code into an example app and ran it, and the EditText disappears completely. Could you show any code you've written for the EditText in your main class file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be this line in your "**etBody**" `EditText`

```
android:isScrollContainer="true"
```

I believe this makes the EditText resize itself to fit the content inside it. Therefore because you have nothing inside it, it disappears.

Comment: Ah ha, that worked! Eclipse must've added that in there from where I added it through the GUI. I was filling it with some text in my code beforehand and it was still resizing itself to where you couldn't read anything but oh well, problem solved. Thanks!